# jquery file upload with blueimp fails when file selected in multiple iterations

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using blueimp file upload. The file upload feature is working for me when i'm selecting multiple files simultaneously i.e. when i select multiple files from single folder and upload them the feature works fine, all of my files get uploaded.

But problem is when i select multiple files in different iterations i.e. single file in a first iteration, again single file in second iteration and so on. So in this case only last file which I select got upload. The fileupload forgets the previously selected file.

I tried with `sequentialUploads = true`.  but it doesn't help.

Do you have any idea how to upload multiple files selected in different iterations.

Comment: When I used this plugin I hadn't your problem, but I used a schema to serialize my form parameters because I would like to send additional fields. Something like this:
<pre> <code>
  $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
    if (inputs.filter(function () {
      return !this.value && $(this).prop('required');
    }).first().focus().length) {
      data.context.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      return false;
    }
    data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
  });
</code></pre> 
Just a try...

Answer (score 0):

Es necesario mantener el campo name modo array y la opcion  "multiple"

```
<input type="file" name="foto[]"  id="fileFoto" multiple >
```